# Swipe to slide in new image

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-mobile

I am looking for a script or tutorial in which I can display an image wrapped in an anchor tag and when I swipe to the left or right it displays a new image. This script should work with json and jquery mobile and indicates how many images are within the slideshow. Any such tutorial?

Comment: Why do you need json or jquery mobile to achieve this ? See if this helps http://cubiq.org/dropbox/SwipeView/demo/gallery/

Comment: Well I want it to fit well in a mobile setting and well the json part actually not neccessar yas I can just switch it to html code

Comment: I had integrated SwipeView with apps on Mobile Safari and Android tablets and was greatly impressed. IScroll can also be tweaked a little to achieve what you want. Do take a look, they have some great demos to give you and idea.

Comment: the swipeview looks very clean am looking at it now

Answer (score 1):

[**Awesome Mobile Image Gallery**](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/05/27/awesome-mobile-image-gallery-web-app/)

Can be used as a static image gallery or load images dynamically via `$.ajax`.

Comment: this seems very complicated and I don't want the thumbs

Comment: @KernElliott You can mofify it. Consider it a tutorial ;)

Comment: :D will take a look but swipeview seems great atm

Answer (score 0):

I myself wrong the simplest form of image slider using jQuery for jQuery Mobile.

You can find the [Tutorial here](http://itdiary.mayuonline.com/simple-basic-image-carousel-with-jquery-mobile/) and the [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/R3bZ8/13/).

Following is the core

```
$("#myImagePage").swiperight(function () {
        if (i < (imgURL.length - 1)) {
            i++
        } else {
            i = 0;
        }
        var imgStr = "<img src=" + imgURL[i] + " style='width:100%'>";
        $('#ImageDiv').html(imgStr);
    });
    $("#myImagePage").swipeleft(function () {
        if (i > 0) {
            i--
        } else {
            i = (imgURL.length - 1);
        }
        var imgStr = "<img src=" + imgURL[i] + " style='width:100%'>";
        $('#ImageDiv').html(imgStr);
    });
```

Comment: This is great but it needs a bit more animation for the change between the images ah nice slide animation would be nice